# VoiceOver won't announce NSAccessibility Notification

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, appkit, voiceover

I'm working to add accessibility to a custom UI element in an existing macOS codebase. We've got a custom error window that appears when an error occurs, and I'm trying to get VoiceOver to announce the error when it occurs.

Currently, I'm trying to use the [`NSAccessibility.post(element: Any, notification: NSAccessibility.Notification, userInfo: [NSAccessibility.NotificationUserInfoKey : Any]?)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibility/1534572-post) method, but while the code is run, the notification is not spoken.

Here's what I've currently got in my NSViewController:

```swift
NSAccessibility.post(element: self, notification: .announcementRequested, userInfo: [
    .announcement: NSLocalizedString("CANT_CONNECT_ERROR", comment: "Error string for connection failure"),
    .priority: NSAccessibilityPriorityLevel.high
])
```

My expectation was that, using the `.announcementRequested` option, VoiceOver should automatically pick this up and speak the announcement, but no luck. I've tried using different notification types, tried putting in a hardcoded string value in the `.announcement` argument, and tried using `.rawValue` and `90` for the `.priority` argument.

Comment: Does it help if you post the notificcation against NSApp instead of self? The documentation indicates it should be posted against NSApp but some archived accessibility-dev conversation suggests maybe it needs to be posted against a window or something instead. Maybe try a few different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to get this to work after much trial and error (and [danielpunkass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69768/danielpunkass)'s helpful comments). YMMV, but here's how I got it to work:

1. The `element` argument has to be set to `NSApp.mainWindow` (I've added `as Any` as well to silence a compiler warning)
2. The priority level in the `userInfo` dictionary has to be set using the `.rawValue`, not the actual enum value. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibility/notification/1530633-announcementrequested) does not mention this of course.

Here's my working code:

```swift
NSAccessibility.post(
    element: NSApp.mainWindow as Any,
    notification: .announcementRequested,
    userInfo: [
        .announcement: "This is a custom accessibility notification",
        .priority: NSAccessibilityPriorityLevel.high.rawValue
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An old conversation on the Accessibility-Dev mailing list suggests that this notification may need to be directed at NSApp's mainWindow:

https://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2013/Jul/msg00027.html

Maybe this will do the trick for you as well?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Daniel. I always forget to check the old mailing list for things like this.

I tried the suggestions, but unfortunately wasn't able to get it to work by referencing `NSApp` or the main window, or any permutation.

Comment: Bah, sorry to hear that! I wish it were easier to debug VoiceOver's behavior when it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to announce text on macOS and hisaac's answer solved my issue. Since I have multi-platform app, I created some helper extensions which I can use across iOS, macOS and tvOS. They can be improved for sure, especially in terms of naming, but since there is anyway not so much around when it comes to accessibility, I thought I share anything I have:

```swift
import SwiftUI

#if os(macOS)
public typealias PlatformAccessibility = NSAccessibility
#else
public typealias PlatformAccessibility = UIAccessibility
#endif

public enum AccessibilityNotification {
    case platformAnnouncement
    
    fileprivate var platformNotification: PlatformAccessibility.Notification {
        switch self {
#if os(macOS)
        case .platformAnnouncement:
            return .announcementRequested
#else
        case .platformAnnouncement:
            return .announcement
#endif
        }
    }
}

public extension PlatformAccessibility {
    
    static var isVoiceOverEnabled: Bool {
#if os(macOS)
        NSWorkspace.shared.isVoiceOverEnabled
#else
        UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning
#endif
    }
    
    static func post(notification: AccessibilityNotification, argument: Any?, delay: Double = 0, queued: Bool = false) {
#if os(macOS)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay + (queued ? 1 : 0)) {
            NSAccessibility.post(
                element: NSApp.mainWindow as Any,
                notification: notification.platformNotification,
                userInfo: [
                    .announcement: argument as Any,
                    .priority: NSAccessibilityPriorityLevel.high.rawValue
                ]
            )
        }
#else
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            var message = argument
            if let argument = argument as? String, queued {
                message = NSAttributedString(string: argument, attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechQueueAnnouncement: true])
            }
            PlatformAccessibility.post(notification: notification.platformNotification, argument: message)
        }
#endif
    }
}
```